# Standard Notation For The Set of All the Morphisms Of A Category

Tags: notation, category-theory

Let $\mathscr C$ be a category.

Let $\text{Ob}(\mathscr C)$ be the set of all the objects of $\mathscr C$.

Is there a standard notation for $\bigcup_{A,B\in\text{Ob}(\mathscr C)}\text{Mor}(A,B)$?

And is $\text{Ob}(\mathscr C)$ the standard notation for the set of all the objects of $\mathscr C$?

Comment: Careful now: Typically $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is not a set, and so your *class* of all morphisms would not be a set either.

Comment: @AlexG. Thank you for the response. I have just started reading the basics of category theory and I cannot see why $\text{Ob}(\mathscr C)$ is not a set. Can't I just collect all the objects of $\mathscr C$ in a set and call it $\text{Ob}(\mathscr C)$?

Comment: It turns out that this does not really work. Take, for example, the category of sets. Then $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ would be the "set of all sets." However, it's well known that there is no such set. Assuming its existence violates the standard (ZF) axioms of set theory. For this reason, we instead call $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ a *class*, and do not require that it satisfies those axioms.

Comment: By the way, there are some categories in which $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set. These are often called "small" categories (since $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is "small" enough to be a set).

Comment: @AlexG. Thank you. I think I can say goodbye to half my knowledge of mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think usually people denote it by $Mor(\mathscr{C})$. You should be careful, because it is not always a set (if the category $\mathscr{C}$ is big) as Alex G. pointed out in his comment.  But this union of all morphisms is always again a category with object being morphisms in $\mathscr{C}$ and maps between morphisms being the obvious commutative squares.

Comment: I don't agree with "is ... a category ...". Rather "is the object class of a category ..." or "may be enriched to a category ...". Don't forget forgetful functors ;).